# java: how to check if two arrays contain common elements?

Tags: java

Is there any easy way to check if two arrays contain any common elements?
Is this appropriate? The arrays contain type char.

```
Arrays.asList(encryptU).contains(Ualpha[randNum]));
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the element type. What is the type?

Comment: What are your arrays?? Can you post it here??

Comment: Also your description doesn't go along with your title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the arrays are small, then a solution with a nested for loop (e.g. @scaryrawr's) is going to perform best.

If the arrays are large enough, then the `O(N^2)` complexity of the above solution will be problematic.  The solution is to use a HashSet; e.g.

```
HashSet<Character> tmp = new HashSet<Character>();
for (char ch : arr1) {
    tmp.add(ch);
}
for (char ch : arr2) {
    if (tmp.contains(ch)) {
        // elements in common!!
    }
}
```

This is `O(N)` in time, though the constant of proportionality is rather large.  (I think you'd need the product of the array sizes to be 20 or 30 for this to be faster than the nested loop solution ... but that is a guess.)  Also, this requires `O(N)` temporary space.

---

If the *range* of the characters is limited, then you could use a `BitSet` instead of a `HashSet`.  That will also be roughly `O(N)` in time and space, though the range of the characters is also a factor in the complexity, so calling it `O(N)` is an over-simplification.

---

But we are probably "over-thinking" this.  The best advice would probably be to implement something simple, and if there is a suspicion that performance is a real concern then **profile it** to avoid wasting your time with *unnecessary* optimizing.

Comment: shouldn't `Char` here be `Character`?

Comment: Yes - and someone kindly fixed that typo for me.

Comment: Hi @StephenC your solution is really good for large input array. I just want to know for your solution Time complexity is O(N) or O(a+b) where a is length of arr1 and b is length of arr2. Just I have doubt therefore want to clarify

Comment: @PPD - it is `O(A + B)`, compared with `O(A * B)`  for the nested loop solution. *But you should be able to work that out for yourself!*   When you have a doubt, work it out!

Comment: @StephenC I am started learning Data Structure now, so As per me it was O(a+b) therefore for confirmation I asked you. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: @PPD - If you are learning about data structures they should have explained to you how to work out Big O complexity from first principles.  My suggestion is to try to do it ... as a learning exercise.  (And if they haven't taught you yet, go look in your data structures textbook.)

Answer (score 0):

Any common elements:

```
char[] a = {...};
char[] b = {...};
boolean hasCommon = false;
for (char alpha : a) {
    for (char beta : b) {
        if (alpha == beta) {
            hasCommon = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasCommon) { break; }
}
```

Just checking if some random position in one is contained in the other will give you some false negatives.

Comment: Why are you indexing through array?? You can use enhanced-for loop..

Comment: Updated =] (actually I forgot...)

Comment: That looks pretty simple now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
Character[] arr1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
Character[] arr2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}

boolean matches = arr.toString().equals(arr2.toString());
```

This checks if the two arrays are exactly equal.

If you want to see if they have common,

```
List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(arr1);
List<Character> chars2 = Arrays.asList(arr2);

boolean matches = (chars.retainAll(chars2).size()==0)?false:true;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works now. I've successfully compiled and ran it with `gcj`

Comment: Yes.  It runs now, but it no longer solves the OP's problem.  He wants to compare `char[]` not `Character[]` arrays.